# How many strings of six lowercase letters have at least one vowel?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

> The English alphabet has $21$ consonants and $5$ vowels. How many strings of six lowercase letters have at least one vowel?

---

My attempt:

I'm confused between using combinations and just counting the options. For this, why is $C(26,6) - C(21,6)$ wrong and $26^6 - 21^6$ right? I don't understand the difference between $C(26,6)$ and $26^6$. When should I use combinations and when should I use exponents?

Answer (score 1):

Answering the title:

- The number of $6$-letter strings is $(21+5)^6$
- The number of $6$-letter strings with no vowels is $21^6$
- The number of $6$-letter strings with at least one vowel is $(21+5)^6-21^6$

---

Answering the body:

- The number of $6$-different-letter combinations is $\binom{21+5}{6}$
- The number of $6$-different-letter combinations with no vowels is $\binom{21}{6}$
- The number of $6$-different-letter combinations with at least one vowel is $\binom{21+5}{6}-\binom{21}{6}$

---

Answering related question:

- The number of $6$-different-letter permutations is $\binom{21+5}{6}\cdot6!$
- The number of $6$-different-letter permutations with no vowels is $\binom{21}{6}\cdot6!$
- The number of $6$-different-letter permutations with at least one vowel is $\binom{21+5}{6}\cdot6!-\binom{21}{6}\cdot6!$

Comment: What would the difference between "The number of 6-letter strings with no vowels" and "The number of 6-different-letter combinations with no vowels" mean?

Comment: @thethethe: the word "**different**"!!!

Answer (score 0):

In short, although I am 100% sure this is in your textbook (and, to be honest, if you don't know that it is in your textbook and your test is tommorow, I don't have high hopes for you...): If you are picking $k$ items out of $n$ and:

- order matters and you are not replacing the items: $n\cdot (n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)$
- order matters and you are replacing the items: $n^k$
- order doesn't matter and you are **not** replacing the items: ${n\choose k}$

Comment: Somebody just downvoted all the posts here.

Comment: @barakmanos I think it's the "this question is so lazy it doesn't deserve an answer" kind of downvote. I almost agree with it. The OP has a test **tommorow** and only decided to study the stuff today, and wants full answers that will enlighten him...

Comment: I agree with everything you said, except for the "almost agree with" part.

Comment: @barakmanos Well by that I mean I agree that there is a "laziness threshold" under which a question should not get any answers. I don't think this particular question is there, but if someone has a different threshold, then it's reasonable he would downvote the answers.